# Partial residual plot not informative but transformations of predictor variables are required?

Tags: logistic, residuals, diagnostic, fractional-polynomial

I have fitted a binary logistic regression model with two explanatory variables: $x_1,x_2$ using fractional polynomials (60k observations)(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mfp/vignettes/mfp_vignette.pdf). The regression function and its transformation of the variables suggests

$\text{logit}(p(x)) = -7\times10^{-6} x_1^2 + 6.3 x_2^{0.5} - 14.5 \log x_2$

With these transformation of $x_1,x_2$ I get a substantial decrease in residual deviance compared to keeping these as linear terms . (Null deviance: 13951(intercept) ,Residual deviance 13814(linear), residual deviance 12624 (transformation))

Keeping these variables linear gives:

$\text{logit}(p(x)) = -0.0035x_1 - 0.0079x_2$

I would like to confirm that these transformations(fractional polynomials) seem reasonable using a partial residual plot (`crPlots`). But looking at the  graphs the smoother (green line) suggests keeping $x_1,x_2$ linear.

[image]

Why does the partial residual plot not suggest that I would transform the variables when such transformations lead to a substantial decrease in residual deviance?

Here are plots of the(transformed) functional form of $x_1,x_2$:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you've partially answered your own question. Over the observed ranges of your predictors, the transformed alternatives aren't especially strongly nonlinear. (The graphs would be better with the _x_ axes reversed, or equivalently with consistent signs.)

Comment: Does it matter that the drop in residual deviance is about 1200  with the transformed variables compared to the linear? @Nick Cox

Comment: As usual, you can get a closer fit with a more complicated model. I can't tell you whether that complication is worthwhile for your purposes. The dataset is too big for you to post easily, so I won't ask to see it. What I can't guess at is  whether your predictors should be complemented by interaction terms. The implication of non-monotonicity is important too. Subject-matter knowledge on what the variables are should also inform model choice.